# Tracking viewed content

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume I have something like an RSS reader, where I have a ton of available items, and I only want to show the items my user has not read.

What's the best way to track what's been read that won't result in super dirty queries? I'm trying to avoid a huge `$nin: [12312, 1341, 134234, ..]` situation. After say a year of usage, you'd have millions of items and then at least thousands in your "read" array.

The other option I can think of is to keep a collection for each user, and when a new item comes in, add it to each user who has that feed's collection. That seems cleaner over time, but what if I have large turnover and say 30% of my users stop using the site. Their collections will just collect tons of data? I could prune these collections after a while, but I'm not sure that's fair either. What if they went on vacation?

Both of these solutions seem super gross to me, am I missing a better way?

NOTE: My question is tagged and the result will be written for Mongo, but the answer does not need to be specific to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be the most effective for chronological data, is just keeping a log of the oldest content seen per user, and a separate list of any "mark as unread" items that don't fit.

I think this is actually a pretty good reason to either sort things like this chronologically, or at the very least incorporate it into your algorithm so you can calculate max ages of relevant content, to keep your queries doable.

If it is truly non-chronological data, then you'll have to keep a collection of items per user.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to store a user id of users who have read an item in the item document. Then you can search for articles where the `read` array does not contain the user's ID.

Obviously if you have a lot of users, you'll have a document growth issue.

Comment: Yeah, assume 10k+ users.

Comment: So then if you use an ObjectID, it will use 120KB+ of each document if every user looks at that item.

Comment: Which is the same amount if I store unread per user and no one reads. The difference would be that I can limit those if necessary, and a typical user would read most of their content. So while space isn't the only concern, the unread list would use far less. Hmmmmm.

Comment: I thought about an unread list, but you'd have to add to all of these unread lists each new registered user.

Comment: Well you wouldnt' add all of them I guess. Maybe the last 100 or so. That'd still take up considerably less space than marking each item with each user. An Unread list would have like 10k writes associated with each new piece of content though...

Comment: Whoa, that's unnecessary, cause we know when your last visit was. You'd get unread + content since last visit, then add the new stuff to unread. That way the writes are distributed to actual usage and not dogpiled on content addition (which is frequent). I dunno if that'd be better than a batch insert.